# C: Function not returning value to main

Tags: c, function

I want to get the value of "length" input with the get_length function to be sent up to main, but I get an error on the printf statement following get_length(); in main. Apparently it's tossing away whatever is entered with scanf. How do I make it keep the new value entered by the user?

```
void get_length(int length);
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
int length;
int width;
int area;
get_length();
printf("The length of the rectangle is %d.\n", length);
return 0;
}

void get_length(int length)
{
printf("Please enter the length for a rectangle: ");
scanf("%d", &length);

while(length < 1)
{
    printf("Enter a positive number.\n");
    scanf("%d", &length);
}
return;
}
```

Comment: `get_length(&length)`

Comment: Error near line 11: Reading an uninitialized value from address 61400  Line 11 being the printf("The length)

Comment: THis shouldn't even compile. get_length() is called without a parameter.

Comment: You aren't passing the length parameter to get length, and even if you did, you are passing length by value so it won't be changed.  Pass by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int get_length();
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
int length;
int width;
int area;
length = get_length();
printf("The length of the rectangle is %d.\n", length);
return 0;
}

int get_length()
{
int length;
printf("Please enter the length for a rectangle: ");
scanf("%d", &length);

while(length < 1)
{
    printf("Enter a positive number.\n");
    scanf("%d", &length);
}
return length;
}
```

You can return `length` in get_length() function as above. Or use `pointer` instead like follow:

```
void get_length(int* length);
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
int length;
int width;
int area;
get_length(&length);
printf("The length of the rectangle is %d.\n", length);
return 0;
}

void get_length(int* length)
{
printf("Please enter the length for a rectangle: ");
scanf("%d", length);

while(*length < 1)
{
    printf("Enter a positive number.\n");
    scanf("%d", length);
}
return;
}
```

in c++, you could use `reference`

Comment: Thanks, the second one with void seems to work!

Answer (score 2):

What about changing the signature of your function? from `void get_length(int length)` to  `int get_length();`

```
int get_length()
{
   int length = 0;
   printf("Please enter the length for a rectangle: ");
   scanf("%d", &length);

   while(length < 1)
   {
      printf("Enter a positive number.\n");
      scanf("%d", &length);
   }
   return length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get the job done. The first is to actually return `length`:

```
int get_length(void)
{
    int length;
    // get length
    return length;
}
```

and in `main`:

```
int length;

length = get_length();
```

The second is to pass a pointer and modify what the pointer point:

```
void get_length(int* length_ptr)
{
    scanf("%d", length_ptr);
}
```

in `main`:

```
get_length(&length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues, one you are not passing any parameters to `get_length`, second you need to pass the parameter as a *pointer* in order to get the value back:

```
void get_length(int *length)
```

the the `scanf` would change to this:

```
scanf("%d", length);
```

and the *while* to this:

```
while(*length < 1)
```

and finally you call in `main` would be:

```
get_length(&length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call get_length with a parameter.

Like this:

```
get_length(&length);
```

And have the method take an int* as parameter.

```
void get_length(int* length)
```

Then it can store the value in length for you.